# C++ (pre C++11) fstream initialized by sstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to open other process stdin and write to it, using C++, no dup() and other C tricks. But unfortunately, fstream constructor taking string seems to be available only from C++11 ( source:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/ )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

//using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // std::cout << "child:" << i << std::endl;
        std::string line;
        std::cin.sync();
        std::cout << "child got message:" << std::endl;
        while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) )
        {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;

        }
        std::cout << "child done receiving" << std::endl;


    }
    else{
        //std::cout << "parent"<<std::endl;
        std::ifstream file("stdin", std::ios::in);
        if(file.is_open())
        {
        std::string tmp, str;

        std::stringstream pidstr;
        pidstr << "/proc/" << pid << "/fd/0";

        while ( std::getline(file, tmp) )
            str += tmp + "\n";

        std::fstream other( (pidstr.str().c_str()), std::ios::out);
        other << str ;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have four questions:

1. Is "pidstr.str().c_str()" most C++ way to do it? Looks ugly to me.
2. Is that proper C++ way or maybe there are better alternatives?
3. Since, as far as I know, getline() is blocking, can I ommit cin.sync(), expecting child to wait for input in while ?
4. Why do I need to press enter twice, (regardless if i have getchar in child commented out or not(!))

Thanks for understanding.

EDIT: This compiles, and produces desired output, using Code:Blocks, Linux 13.04

EDIT2: No, apparently this does NOT produce desired output. I've added some changes: parent waits for child to exit (not important here).

But also changed this (in child) :

```
    while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) )
    {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "child done" << std::endl;
```

to this :

```
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    int lines; // this is single line sent as first from parent, containing int
    std::istringstream toint(line);
    toint >> lines;
    std::cout << "how much lines should it read:" << lines << std::endl;
```

And it appears that child will wait for anything on stdin, then prints out that what was sent from parent. Really, sometimes I wonder how should i consider C++ as better than plain C :/

Comment: There's always `std::ofstream other(pidstr.str());` in C++11 (although you should be using `std::ofstream` anyway).

Comment: I've tried this way but include  <ofstream> gave me error. I thought this as weird, but anyway probably best to include less than more libraries (?)

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. There are much better ways, but I wouldn't be able to fit in this comment; 3. Don't even use `sync()`, its behavior is implementation-defined and mostly likely won't do anything useful for you; 4. I think that might be a bug. But I should look closer into your code to be certain.

Comment: Mhm. Regarding (2): This needs not to be cross platform, and needs to deliver data to other pid stdin. What would be one of those much better ways? 3 : I read that i actually should use sync or clear, somewhere on SO :) confusing at least, but i  wouldnt use it if getline was sure to wait for parent in while (regardless if child began executing and got to while loop before parent sent input)

Comment: @user41632, It's in `<fstream>`, just like the `std::ifstream` you use is.

Comment: @chris : std::ofstream other( pidstr.str() ); \n <br />
/tmp/1/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/tmp/1/main.cpp|47|error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)’

Comment: @user41632, That specific constructor is only there in C++11.

Comment: `dup` is not a "C trick". It's a POSIX.1-2001 API, just like `fork`.